# Synonymize and merge [tvp] to [table-valued-parameters]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

### Synonymize and merge [tvp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tvp) to [table-valued-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table-valued-parameters)

Tags mean the same. You can verify this by reading tag descriptions. Also description of [tvp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tvp) seems to be more detailed so it should be moved to main tag after merging.

Comment: I see no reason, why would it be offtopic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tags have been synonymized and merged in the following manner:

[table-valued-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table-valued-parameters) × 260 ← [tvp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tvp) × 69

Some stats while merging:

```
updating post history, 102 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 76 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 69 rows affected
```